# Orthogonal Linear Regression (total least squares) fit, get RMSE and R-squared in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, data-fitting

I am trying to fit a model that linearly relates two variables using R. I need to fit a Orthogonal Linear Regression (total least squares). So I'm trying to use the `odregress()` function of the pracma package which performs an [Orthogonal Linear Regression via PCA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/how-to-perform-orthogonal-regression-total-least-squares-via-pca).

Here an example data:

```
x <- c(1.0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.4, 0.2, 0.7, 1.0, 1.1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.1, 1.3, 0.9)
y <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 1.2, 1.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8)
```

I'm able to fit the model and get the coefficient using:

```
odr <- odregress(y, x)
c <- odr$coeff
```

So, the model is defined by the following equation:

```
print(c)
[1]  0.65145762 -0.03328271
```

Y = 0.65145762*X - 0.03328271

Now I need to plot the line fit, compute the RMSE and the R-squared. How can I do that?

```
plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two functions to compute the MSE and RMSE.

```r
library(pracma)

x <- c(1.0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.4, 0.2, 0.7, 1.0, 1.1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.1, 1.3, 0.9)
y <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 1.2, 1.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8)

odr <- odregress(y, x)

mse_odreg <- function(object) mean(object$resid^2)
rmse_odreg <- function(object) sqrt(mse_odreg(object))

rmse_odreg(odr)
#> [1] 0.5307982
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

The R^2 can be computed with the following function. Note that `odr$ssq` is not the sum of the squared residuals, `odr$resid`, it is the sum of the squared errors, `odr$err`.

```r
r_squared_odreg <- function(object, y) {
  denom <- sum((y - mean(y))^2)
  1 - object$ssq/denom
}
r_squared_odreg(odr, y)
#> [1] 0.1494818
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: To plot the line fit: `plot(x,y)`, and then: `abline(odr$coeff[2], odr$coeff[1])`

Comment: Any idea how can I compute the R-squared?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative to solve an Orthogonal Linear Regression (total least squares) via PCA according to what is explained in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13152/how-to-perform-orthogonal-regression-total-least-squares-via-pca). It actually does the same as `pracma::odregress`.

```
x <- c(1.0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.4, 0.2, 0.7, 1.0, 1.1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.1, 1.3, 0.9)
y <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 1.2, 1.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8)
```

In this case we perform a Principal Component Analysis using the `prcomp()` function.

```
v <- prcomp(cbind(x,y))$rotation
```

Then we calculate the slope (*m*) from the firs principal component and the intercept (*n*):

```
# Y = mX + n
m <- v[2,1]/v[1,1]
n <- mean(y) - (m*mean(x))
```

Our model is defined by: `f <- function(x){(m*x) + n}`

We can plot it using:

```
plot(x, y)
abline(n, m, col="blue")
```

Finally we plot the Total Least Squares fit versus the Ordinary Least Squares fit.

```
plot(x, y)
abline(n, m, col="blue")
abline(lm(y~x), col="red")
legend("topleft", legend=c("TLS", "OLS"), col=c("blue", "red"), lty=1, bty="n")
```

[image: TLS vs OLS]

As you can see we obtain the same results as in `pracma::odregress`:

```
odr <- odregress(y, x)
print(odr$coeff)
print(paste(round(m, digits=7), round(n, digits=7)))

[1] 0.5199081 0.2558142
[1] 0.5199081 0.2558142
```